# Why use verify=True in requests API call?

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests

So, in `requests` in case of SSL verification, we pass `verify=True` or `verify='/path/to/cert`. According to the documentation, passing `verify=True` means that requests checks the SSL certificate on the host. But, in case of passing path to the cert file in `verify` for requests, it considers the specific cert file for authenticating the request.

Then what is the advantage of passing `verify=True` in the first place? Since, even if, I pass `verify=False`, it works correctly. Earlier, I thought, it is generating a self-signed certificate, but I was incorrect. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Before coming to the different values for `verify` one needs to understand first, what this `verify` is about in the first place. It is about **validating that the server certificate matches the expected one**, which means that there is a **direct end-to-end protected connection to the server** and there is **not some man in the middle** who can read and modify the traffic. The server validation is (among other things) based on locally trust root certificates which represent trusted certificate authorities (CA): if no chain from the server provided leaf certificate to any of the local trust anchors can be constructed, then the certificate is not trusted. For more on this see [SSL Certificate framework 101: How does the browser actually verify the validity of a given server certificate?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/56389/ssl-certificate-framework-101-how-does-the-browser-actually-verify-the-validity).

`verify=True` then means that the server validation is done to use the default trust anchors, which are commonly the same public root certificates as used in the browser. `verify=file.pem` means to not use the default trust anchors but instead only the ones given in the specific file. This can be a single CA certificate, can be multiple CA certificates but can also be self-signed certificates expected for a specific server. Both of these options are usually sufficiently secure. But explicitly specifying which CA or certificate is trusted with `verify=file.pem` is more restrictive and thus more secure.

`verify=False` instead means that no certificate validation is done at all. This means a man in the middle will not be detected and thus anybody in the middle could sniff and fiddle with the traffic. **This is totally unsafe and should never be used for critical data.**. Critical data are obviously things like passwords or access tokens, but even exposing the exact URL visited can be considered critical in many cases.