# force https with requests

Tags: python, https, python-requests

**Question**

How do I force `requests` to make HTTPS requests, even if the URL is given as `'http://...'`?

**Related questions**

There are questions similar in title such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20485772/correct-way-to-make-a-python-https-request-using-requests-module) but they're not quite answering my question.

I also looked into the `verify` argument ([link to question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66776029/why-use-verify-true-in-requests-api-call)), but again I'm not quite sure if just setting it to `True` solves the issue.

**Attempt**

My current code just runs any URL through an `assert_https` function before handing it to `requests`.

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse

def assert_https(url: str) -> str:
    components = urlparse(url)
    components = components._replace(scheme='https')
    return components.geturl()
```

Comment: I would do it the way you currently are, by altering the url you ask `requests` to fetch. I don't think `verify=True` will do anything for http:// requests, it is whether to verify the certificate of https requests so will only be relevant when making https:// requests